# Dictionary in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

How do I access the dictionary inside the array?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array({'x': 2, 'y': 5})
```

My initial thought:

```
x['y']
```

> Index Error: not a valid index

```
x[0]
```

> Index Error: too many indices for array

Answer (score 20):

You have a 0-dimensional array of object dtype. Making this array at all is probably a mistake, but if you want to use it anyway, you can extract the dictionary by indexing the array with a tuple of no indices:

```
x[()]
```

or by calling the array's [`item`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method:

```
x.item()
```

Comment: Ok, Nvidia Modulus uses this kind of numpy array to export model's output. This was super useful.

Comment: I ended up with such a 0-dimensional array after using `np.savez_compressed` to save a few variables, including a `dict`, and then loading them again. I was as perplexed as OP, so this is still a relevant answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you add square brackets to the array assignment you will have a 1-dimensional array:

```
x = np.array([{'x': 2, 'y': 5}])
```

then you could use:

```
x[0]['y']
```

I believe it would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
# json & dict -> tuple 
djson = json.loads('{"Foo": "bar", "Loreum": "ipsum"}') # json -> dict
dict2tupls = []
n = 0
for i in djson.items():
    dict2tupls += [i]

make_nparray = np.array(dict2tupls)

print(dict2tupls)
print(make_nparray)
print(make_nparray.shape)
```

Dictionary:

> [('Foo', 'bar'), ('Loreum', 'ipsum')]

nparray:

> [['Foo', 'bar'], ['Loreum', 'ipsum']]

nparray Dimensions:

> (2, 2)

This is the solution I came up with, convert keys:value into tuples.
Handle dimensions accordingly..